# Enable scrolling for Custom task pane in excel

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm developing excel plugin, I have WPF control added to custom task pane in excel,  when docking a custom pane to the left some controls at the end of the pane doesn't display.
I want to apply scrolling for the custom task pane how can I achieve that

here is my code

```
 CustomerPane ctp = new CustomerPane();

 CustomTaskPane _customerTaskPane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(new 
 WpfPanelHost{ Child = ctp }, "Customers");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem, I added scroll viewer to the WPF user control and fixed my problem

```
  <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"> 
         //content here 
   </ScrollViewer>
```